# query for records in 1 table where 2nd table depicts whether a record requires field to be filled

Tags: mysql, sql, visual-studio-2010, oracle

I have 1 table (master_tbl) with records and data and one table that depicts which fields require data (lookup_tbl).

I am trying to join the code fields as the key and the other fields have identical names.

Please see picture for example tables and before/after expected results.
http://tinypic.com/r/kf31ci/5

For some reason I can't figure this out. Is it really easy or should I just do it in VB.NET?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your lookup_tbl contains bits instead of letters Y/N (so Y = 1, N = 0), you can do something like the below.

NOTE: It looks from your posted picture that if reqd is N in your lookup table, then the row will always be invalid, so I've done that explicitly in the CASE statement below.

```
SELECT
mt.tag, 
mt.code,
lt.reqd,
mt.color,
mt.fruit
CASE 
  WHEN lt.reqd = 0 THEN 0
  WHEN ISNULL(NULLIF(mt.color, ''),0) = lt.color AND ISNULL(NULLIF(mt.fruit, ''), 0) = lt.fruit THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END AS valid 
FROM master_tbl AS mt
INNER JOIN lookup_tbl AS lt ON mt.code = lt.code
```

Comment: thanks. Is there a way to do this without listing each field since my field names are identical in both tables? I have a lot of fields...

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you'll have to name the fields you're going to compare.